# Open pdf as tab in running instance of xpdf

Tags: terminal, osx, pdf

I am really fond of xpdf but would like to have a tab-based workflow.

If I open a pdf with `xpdf file.pdf` and then open another pdf with `xpdf file2.pdf` the scond file is opened in a new instance of xpdf. Is it possible to have it opened as a tab in the first instance of xpdf?

I am on OSX.

Comment: Do you have access to a version of `xpdf` that supports [the `-remote` option](https://www.xpdfreader.com/xpdf-man.html#REMOTE%20SERVER%20MODE) (the one from Homebrew on macOS does _not_, for example)?

Comment: It's the homebrew version I've got. Is it possible to get another version, with -remote, on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that xpdf can open multiple instances of pdf files. An easy way to do this is opening multiple pdfs in a browser (I do this, works for my use case).

You can try and open more pdfs with `qpdfview` but the last time I used it, it crashed often.

Comment: You *can* open multiple pdfs in one instance of xpdf with `xpdf file1.pdf file2.pdf`. They show up as two tabs in the same instance. The question is whether you can add more files to a running instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you always open your files with the command `xpdf -open`.